# Custom field type - how inherit attributes from base field type

Tags: 2010, development, visual-studio, custom-field-types, spfield

I need to create custom field type which must inherit ATTRIBUTES from inherited field type (e.g. Note). 
I know how to add custom attribute on my custom type (using fldtypes...xml, custom ascx,...) but I can't preserve its additional attributes which mean that only my custom attribute is visible on my custom field type. I assume that base types have some .ascx which contain additional attributes for that type, but I can't find it. Also if somebody know where it is (maybe in ...\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES ?!?), how can i extend it for my inherited type ?

Please, any suggestion will be appreciated!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the built-in fields don't have Control Templates as such: They're built straight into the Add/Edit Column page.

Your best (and probably only) option to the recreate that section of the form yourself.